# When does the community user start bumping old questions?

Tags: support, questions, community-user

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) the community user bumps old unanswered questions so that they get another shot at getting answered.

I've seen it do it a couple times in the past but it doesn't seem like it's a regular thing. It doesn't seem like it's doing it hourly as is stated in the meta.SO answer.

Is this something that just kicks in after X amount of days or after a certain threshold?

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [What does it mean when a post is bumped to homepage by the Community?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/16977/1406746) – and a related FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange: [What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/335251)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Community](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community) user bumps some number* of randomly chosen questions per hour that meet the following criteria.

1. Is not closed
2. Does not have an accepted answer
3. Does not have an upvoted answer
4. Hasn't been bumped (by users or automated actions) in last 30 days
5. Has a non-negative score

<sub>*On AskUbuntu, this number is 1.  It varies across the network.</sub>

Comment: It seems that the community user is now bumping questions with more frequency. I don't know if this is a result of questions getting older now or if our unanswered question count is triggering it, but it seems "about right" now.

Comment: Is the number* still same for Ask Ubuntu? It's been about 2.5 years :)

Comment: Yes, 1 is the default value of that site setting. It's currently only customized to a different value on a few sites on the network.