# Who is `community` bumping questions to `home page`?

Tags: discussion, community, ubuntu-community

As per my comment [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265939/unable-to-change-the-refresh-rate-to-60hz-with-xrandr) I don't think this question should have been bumped to the home page. The question is abandoned: OP hasn't signed on in 4+ years, 2 days after question was posted. Therefor extremely unlikely to respond to comments or confirm or deny answers. The question is about EOL Ubuntu 12.04 which none of us in our right minds would be running and therefor unable to duplicate.

But it begs the meta question... "who is the community"? I know I don't have "bump" powers.

Comment: See [What does it mean when a post is bumped to homepage by the Community?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16977/what-does-it-mean-when-a-post-is-bumped-to-homepage-by-the-community), [When does the community user start bumping old questions?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/660/when-does-the-community-user-start-bumping-old-questions), and [Community bumping on AU](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11808/community-bumping-on-au)

Comment: I think we should close this question as a dupe of one of those... But I still disagree with bot  programming in my example

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix if you disagree with how it works, take it to MSE. Community bot is global.

Comment: @Avery [That related idea](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/11808) was for Community to bump differently here. SE would have to implement it, but [it's OK to raise even site-nonspecific ideas on a child meta first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89232). I am [*likely to disagree*](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/11810) with a feature request about this. But if asking for AU-specific behavior, this seems like the best place for it.  ([There is precedent](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/367) for SE granting a feature request for special behavior for just one site, posted on its child meta.)

Comment: @EliahKagan I'm not sure what my question should be a dupe of. The question has been answered: "It's a bot". But the larger issue in the shadows is "Who wrote the bot and why didn't he/she/they know not to bump 4+ y/o abandoned questions pertaining to abandoned (EOL) software?". In my project of going through and voting to close EOL software unanswered questions and particularly those that were abandoned by OP I found oen to place a bounty on and some to ping OP or commenter on to post an answer. A bot could have done the same. In this case I think no bot is better than a badly programmed bot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Community user is a bot. It automatically bumps old messages that fits [the criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/285481).

[From its profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community):

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - **Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention**
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
> - Own suggested edits from anonymous users
> - [Remove abandoned questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006)

You can check the criteria from the link at top of the post and see [this summary by math.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bumping/info) if you want more details.